# Python Tkinter: Is there a way to have text and buttons with the button placed on the x and y axes?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get text and a button where the button is placed using `place()`. See the code:

```
import tkinter as t
w = t.Tk()
w.title("TaxNow Beta")
w.geometry('2000x6000')
c = t.Canvas(w, width="6000", height="2000", bg="White")
frame = t.Frame(w)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
c.create_text(900,50,text="Please Login", font=("Montserrat 32"))
frame.pack()
loginButton = t.Button(frame, text="Log In")
loginButton.place(x=100, y=150)



w.mainloop()
```

The text isn't showing up.
Can someone help?

Comment: you haven't called `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the canvas.

Comment: You have called `frame.pack()` twice, so should one of them be `c.pack(...)` instead? Note also that you have created a 2000x6000 root window, but a 6000x2000 canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to have text and buttons with the button placed on the
> x and y axes?

> I'm trying to get text and a button where the button is placed using
> place()

As Bryan Oakley suggested, pack, place, or grid on the canvas. As acw1668 suggested, called frame.pack() twice.

The problem can be fixed.

Using same code.

- On line 8, change value to 100 instead of 900 or suit your need.
  `c.create_text(100, ...`
- On line 10, remove `frame.pack()`
- On line 12, change this `t.Button(frame, ...` to `t.Button(c, ...`
- On line 14, add this `c.pack()`.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as t
w = t.Tk()
w.title("TaxNow Beta")
w.geometry('200x600')
 
frame = t.Frame(w)
c = t.Canvas(frame, width="6000", height="2000", bg="White")
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
c.create_text(150,50,text="Please Login", font=("Montserrat 32"))
#frame.pack() 

loginButton = t.Button(c, text="Log In", bg='red')
loginButton.place(x=100, y=150)
c.pack() 


w.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

is this what you're trying to do ?

```
import tkinter as tk

w = tk.Tk()
w.title("TaxNow Beta")
w.geometry("400x600")

frame = tk.Frame(w)

login_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Log In", font=("Montserrat 15"))
login_text = tk.Label(frame, text="Please Log In", font=("Montserrat 20"))

login_button.pack(ipadx=25)
login_text.pack(pady=10)

frame.pack(expand=True)

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the text on top of the button?

Comment: of course, just .pack() the text before the button. (switch up the pack statelments)